# Python: Extract folder name from path

Tags: python, path

I have a path as a string in python:

```
path = "/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/folder_d"
```

How can I extract the name of the last folder ("folder_d") from the `path`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=basename#os.path.basename):

```
>>> path = "/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/folder_d"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(path)
'folder_d'
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Your answer will be accepted in a few minutes. Thanks

Comment: if this is the path how will it work path = "/folder_a/folder_b/folder_c/folder_d/"

Comment: Docstring: Returns the final component of a pathname

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try this:

```
y=path.split('/')
last_folder=y[-1]
```

Which is the last item in the list

Comment: If you don't use `os.path.basename()`, you should at least use `os.path.split()`.

Comment: You're probably right. I am only familiar with os' really basic methods and i didn't know this one. Thanks for pointing it out :)